# Line-height/height properties causing <DIV> to scroll?

Tags: css

I don't ever ask questions regarding CSS as I'm usually able to figure them out myself, but for some reason this is stumping me.

I'm using a custom check box I got from a website. The check box is rendered in CSS. That check box is contained in a bordered DIV. However, something in the CSS for the check box is causing the DIV to create vertical scroll bars. What I want is for the DIV to adjust its height to the content, not create a scroll bar.

My guess is that it's either the height or line-height properties--or maybe both:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left: 31px;
    height: 18px; 
    display: block;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I've re-created the problem here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPLYxx

Deleting line-height doesn't solve the problem.  However, if I delete the height property, the scroll bars go away, but the check box is messed up.

I have no idea how to go about fixing this and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Sorry, I should have mentioned this before.  For the example, I set the width to a specific value to recreate the issue. However in the actual page, it's set at 100%. The problem comes up when I shrink the page down (like for mobile) and the DIV's width changes to the size as displayed in the example.

Comment: The line height should be the same value as the height of its container.

Comment: Also, `overflow: hidden;` will hide the scrollbars. Just make sure your dimensions fit the content.

Comment: Have you tried setting a min-width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emOaMo

I think this is what you want? Need to fix your checkbox though.

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left: 31px;
    height: 18px; 
    line-height: 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

UPDATE:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emOaMo

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index:-1000; 
  left:-1000px; 
  overflow: auto; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height:1px; 
  width:1px; 
  margin:-1px; 
  padding:0; 
  border:0;
}

#rmtest {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px #d7d7d7 solid;
  width: 269px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Change the height of #rmtest then

Comment: This is close, but the height of the DIV changes depending on the width of the page (it's responsive--sorry I should have mentioned that before, I've added that bit of info to the original post). So I can't specify 40px as it isn't always 40px. Thanks!

Comment: Look at this. It should be what you want

Comment: Now it works. :) I don't know why I didn't think of that before. I should be able to use a media query to detect when it's mobile and the DIV width is too small and I'll adjust the height accordingly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the rmtest CSS section with:

```
#rmtest {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px #d7d7d7 solid;
    width: 265px;
}
```

It looked fine to me.